# Chrome extension for manipulating webpage by adding an icon next to matched links

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Hello i want to write an extension myself and looking for guides/tutorials. I have never created one but i am good with js and html/php.

I need a tutorial/sample code, and here is what i want to do:
when an extension is loaded, i want to add icon next to the google search results (matched links). What it would do is, it will check all the link in a webpage by matching them with a database (php server mysql) and if a match of a domain is found, then it will simply add an icon next to that link (by ofcourse manipulating dom).

Seems like a fairly simple task to do. So if anybody can help me by showing me a correct path or if there is any similar extension already available to learn from, then please advice.

I would be very grateful, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted.html

Have a browse through this. You'll likely get the hand of it if you're proficient with JS.

Comment: I would start here specifically: http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html